# SQL Server 2008 Database encryption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, transparent-data-encryption

In my company there is MS SQL SERVER 2008 standard edition installed.
My problem is we want to encrypt whole database but in standard edition there is encryption like transparent-data-encryption(TDE) not available and column level encryption is time consuming.
So i want to know is there any alternative method available in sql server gor whole database backup?

Comment: See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/cc278098(v=sql.100)) for alternatives using drive/volume level encryption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For encrypting data files at rest, you can use a third party product called [NetLib Encryptionizer for SQL Server](https://netlibsecurity.com/products/sql-server-encryption/) that basically does TDE through a filter driver.

For encrypting backups, you can use any number of third-party backup products. The most popular ones in alphabetical order are [Idera SQL Safe](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlsafebackup), [Quest Litespeed](https://www.quest.com/products/litespeed-for-sql-server/), and [Red Gate SQL Backup](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/index) - all of which can encrypt backups on any version/edition of SQL Server that they support. I've also seen cheaper ones, but I'd just caution you that you should only use backup products that have 24/7 support available. Don't play around with restores.

I have no affiliation with any of those products. (I used to work for Quest.)